# GIT submodule update * deletes uncommited files

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a GIT repository and inside several SUBMODULES.

The problem is every time someone updates submodule, I try to update my files by calling:

```
$ git submodule update
```

But what happens is it deletes all my uncommited files which is very annoying.
I tried to commit and push the files first but it doesn't let me push:

```
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://dev.ancreative.co.uk/var/git/library/Blocks.git'
To prevent you from losing history, non-fast-forward updates were rejected
Merge the remote changes before pushing again.  See the 'non-fast-forward'
section of 'git push --help' for details.*
```

So I try to call `git submodule update`, but then this deletion happens.

Anyone has any idea what can cause this problem? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

[git submodule update](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule) won't help you solve the "non-fast-forward" situation.
It will only checkout the ref that the parent repo references.
It won't pull anything.

Plus, as mentioned in the [**git book**](http://book.git-scm.com/5_submodules.html):

> `git submodule update` **checks out a specific commit, rather than the tip of a branch**.
>   It's like checking out a tag: the head is detached, so you're not working on a branch.

```
$ git branch
* (no branch)
master
```

> If you want to make a change within a submodule and you have a detached head, then you should create or checkout a branch, make your changes, publish the change within the submodule, and then update the superproject to reference the new commit:

```
$ git checkout master
```

So the fact that an update deletes your files (even if committed first) might be related to the fact you are in a detached branch. (Note: you can still get back your commits made in that detached branch after the '`git submodule update`' erased everything by [looking at the reflog](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reflog.html))

Once you are in a proper branch within a submodule, you can:

- try to `push`
- if it fails because of a non-fast-forward situation, you can `git pull` first to merge with the latest remote commits.
- then `push` again
- finally, get back in the parent repo and `commit` there, to register the new SHA1 of your submodule.