# Converting 'CVS era' repo into git repo's with submodules

Tags: git, cvs, git-submodules

We have a very large ancient flat CVS repo with an example format as below. I have imported each subdir as its own git repo with full history.

```
.
├── liba
├── libb
├── libc
├── prog1
├── prog2
└── prog3
```

Lets say that the 3 programs use libraries in the following way:

```
.
├── prog1
│   ├── liba
│   └── libb
├── prog2
│   ├── libb
│   └── libc
└── prog3
    ├── liba
    └── libc
```

Because CVS allows tagging part of the tree - we tag each library and program release with a version tag. eg `liba_4x23`, `prog3_2x22`.

We also tag the program with every version of library it uses at release (ie `liba_3x19` `libc_7x88`)

If we release a new version of the program without a library tag - the tag stays the earliest version of the program it was used.
Now due to the way the git import works - it actually ends up at the latest version of the program (not to worried about that though)

Git submodules seem to be a very good solution for this - a version of a program can be checked out and it pulls in all the right version of libraries as submodules.

Now since all current programs are at different releases of libraries - I would need to retrofit a submodule at a particular version.

- `prog1` is linked with `libb_4x50`
- `prog2` is linked with `libb_4x70`

Assuming `libb_4x70` is latest version then the example of `prog2` is easy

```
git checkout prog2
cd prog2
git submodule add libb
.... done
```

So how to add `libb` tagged with version (not branched) `4x50` to `prog1`?

Other advice appreciated if you have a better idea :-)

What we may also want to do is go back 3 version of the program and set the appropriate submodules for each version. For either backwards compatibility and also as an example to management on how it will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea of submodules (as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979167/git-submodule-update/1979194#1979194)) is to record a specific commit within a parent repo.

So all you need to do is, after adding `libb`, to checkout the right tag, and then to record that new state within the parent repo:

```
git checkout prog1
cd prog1
git submodule add libb
cd lib
git checkout libb_4x50 # make sure to make a branch 
                       # if you want to do any modification
                       # based on libb_4x50,
cd ..
git add -A .
git commit -m "fix correct libb version"
```

(For the "detached `HEAD`" comment, see "[`git submodule update` * deletes uncommitted files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4518379/git-submodule-update-deletes-uncommited-files/4518950#4518950)")

Comment: Thanks. "The idea of submodules is to record a specific commit within a parent repo." - this is exactly the result I want. That was simpler than I thought.